# Spring stomp - messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, stomp

I am trying to send a message using stomp to a specific user. I created a class to determine the userId.
Here is the code:

- LoginController:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public String login(@RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String password, HttpSession session) {
        session.setAttribute("userId", username);
        System.out.println("userId: " + username);
        return "redirect:/index.html";
    }
    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

- CustomHandshakeHandler (to get useId from session which come from LoginController):

```
public class CustomHandshakeHandler extends DefaultHandshakeHandler {
    @Override
    protected Principal determineUser(org.springframework.http.server.ServerHttpRequest request,
                                      org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketHandler wsHandler,
                                      java.util.Map<String, Object> attributes) {
        ServletServerHttpRequest servletRequest = (ServletServerHttpRequest) request;
        HttpSession session = servletRequest.getServletRequest().getSession();
        String userId = (String) session.getAttribute("userId");
        return ()->userId;
    }
}
```

- WebSocketConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws")
                .setHandshakeHandler(new CustomHandshakeHandler())
                .withSockJS(); 
    }
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        registry.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");
    }
}
```

- On the client, subscribe the `/user/private`:

```
function connect(event) {
    username = document.querySelector('#name').value.trim();
    receive = document.querySelector('#receiver').value.trim();
    if(username) {
        usernamePage.classList.add('hidden');
        chatPage.classList.remove('hidden');
        var socket = new SockJS('/ws');
        stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
        stompClient.connect({}, onConnected, onError);
    }
    event.preventDefault();
}
function onConnected() {
    stompClient.subscribe('/user/private', onMessageReceived);
    // Tell your username to the server
    stompClient.send("/app/chat.addUser",
        {},
        JSON.stringify({sender: username, type: 'JOIN'})
    )
    connectingElement.classList.add('hidden');
}
```

- ChatController:

```
@Controller
public class ChatController {
    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;
    private Logger logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(ChatController.class);
    @MessageMapping("/chat.sendMessage")
    @SendTo("/topic/public")
    public ChatMessage sendMessage(@Payload ChatMessage chatMessage) {
        return chatMessage;
    }
    @MessageMapping("/chat.addUser")
    @SendTo("/topic/public")
    public ChatMessage addUser(@Payload ChatMessage chatMessage,
                               SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor) {
        headerAccessor.getSessionAttributes().put("username", chatMessage.getSender());
        return chatMessage;
    }
    @MessageMapping("/chat.sendPrivateMessage")
    public void sendPrivateMessage(@Payload ChatMessage chatMessage) {
        String Username = chatMessage.getReceiver();
        logger.info("private message from :" + chatMessage.getSender() + " to :" + Username);
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(Username, "/private", chatMessage);
    }
}
```

While I have two users (1 and 2) send private message to each other, they can't get the message, but the console could log their active:

```
userId: 1
2023-10-18T16:18:50.202+08:00  INFO 17240 --- [tboundChannel-1] t.s.f.controller.WebSocketEventListener  : Received a new web socket connection
userId: 2
2023-10-18T16:18:59.751+08:00  INFO 17240 --- [tboundChannel-2] t.s.f.controller.WebSocketEventListener  : Received a new web socket connection
2023-10-18T16:19:03.057+08:00  INFO 17240 --- [boundChannel-19] t.scxy.fusion.controller.ChatController  : private message from :1 to :2
2023-10-18T16:19:05.830+08:00  INFO 17240 --- [boundChannel-22] t.scxy.fusion.controller.ChatController  : private message from :2 to :1
```

What can I do to get both of them to receive the message?

I have try to make the client to subscribe the `/user/{username}/private`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Images are not allowed, update your post with the source code in the plain text format~

Answer (score 0):

`SimpMessagingTemplate#convertAndSendToUser` will internally convert the destination into `userDestinationPrefix + username + destination` (for eg, /user/username/destination. where `/user` is the default userDestinationPrefix). so the following script can be used to subscribe to the messages which is sent using `this.template.convertAndSendToUser(userName, "/private", chatMessage);`

```
const username = 'user1';
stompClient.subscribe(`/user/${username}/private`, message=> {
                            console.log(message.body)
                        });
```

To broadcast events to multiple users, publish messages to a topic (eg., /topic/chatroom1) using `SimpMessagingTemplate#convertAndSend` and subscribe to that in script as follows.

```
stompClient.subscribe(`/topic/chatroom1`, message=> {
                            console.log(message.body)
                        });
```

Also register '/user' as part of the messageBroker list

```
registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/user");
```

Ref: https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/